# Default call to __init__ when creating an instance

Tags: python, oop, instance

Just wanted some help understanding these lines of code:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        print("instance created")

parent1=Parent()
parent2=Parent.__init__(parent1)
```

output

```
instance created
instance created
```

I am trying to understand how a constructor is called in OOP for python.

In the first line the the method `__init__` is called by default and the self argument that is passed is somehow `parent1`?

The second line is the more traditional way I would've thought methods would be called. Since `__init__` takes an instance of the `parent` class as an argument I passed `parent1` and it works. I get what is happening in the second line, just wanted to ask what the computer is doing to create the instance `parent1` in the first line.

Comment: In the first line, it would be better to say that the value of `self` is the object that will eventually be assigned to `parent1`.  It isn't right to say that it *is* `parent1`, because the variable doesn't exist yet!

Comment: That is the object created by `__new__` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`__init__` is not a *constructor*, it's an *initializer*. When Python creates an object, it's actually created in `__new__` (usually left as the default, which just makes an empty object of the right class), which receives a reference to the class, and returns an instance (typically empty; no attributes set). The resulting instance is passed implicitly as the `self` in `__init__`, which then establishes the instance attributes.

Typically, you don't call special methods like `__init__` directly (aside from cases involving `super()` with cooperative inheritance), you just let Python do it for you. The only way to *avoid* calling `__init__` would be to explicitly invoke the class's `__new__` (which is also extremely unusual).

Comment: I was mainly doing this as an exercise to test my understanding since I first saw this case when looking at inheritance (as you mentioned). Can I ask what the exact difference between a constructor and initialiser is?

Comment: Reading more carefully - `__new__` constructs an object of the right class hence is the constructor here? Whereas, `__innit__` just takes the created instance and establishes any of the attributes specified, so is called as an initialiser?

Comment: It's a distinction that only exists in python. `__new__` receives a class and the passed in arguments, and returns an object. It is the constructor. `__init__` receives an object and is expected to mutate it based on the arguments. Most other OO languages have a "constructor" that functions more like the "initializer"

Comment: @V.Jain: You got it. Python *can* do both construction and initialization in `__new__` (it's the recommended way to write immutable classes, as it prevents `__init__` being called multiple times and modifying the instance in unexpected ways), but historically, `__new__` didn't even exist; `__init__` was all there was, and the built-in object construction machinery was solely responsible for making the (empty) instance itself. `__init__` saves a couple lines that `__new__` avoids (invoking the parent's `__new__` to get the instance, explicilty `return`ing the instance).

Comment: The distinction between a constructor and an initializer does exist outside of Python, but the terminology is not used consistently. For example, Java's "constructors" are really initializers, because it's possible to acquire a reference to an object which exists in memory (i.e. has been constructed) but whose so-called "constructor" has not yet been executed.

Answer (score 0):

`__init__` is the equivalent to a constructor in Python. Think of an object oriented language as one that has a mandatory argument for functions that represent object methods, so you always have access to that object in that function. Most languages don't make you type out the way you pass in `this`. Python uses `self`, and makes you type it out for every method. It's the same thing, it's just not doing extra work for you.

So when Python instantiates a class, it passes the class to the class's `__new__` function, generates an object, and then passes that object to the class's `__init__` function as the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that `__init__()` work like a constructor, is automatically runs when an object is instantiated (as would happen with Java constructor, if that helps). Although you can call `__init__`, you shouldn't call functions/methods starting with `_` or `__`, they are meant to be called from with the class/object.

When `self` appears as a parameter in a class method you won't have to supply the object's name, Python will figure it out. So the second line above (`Parent2 = ...`) is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation:

[`object.__init__(self[, ...])`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__)

> Called after the instance has been created (by `__new__()`), but before it is returned to the caller. The arguments are those passed to the class constructor expression.

[`object.__new__(cls[, ...])`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__)

> Called to create a new instance of class *cls*. `__new__()` is a static method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such) that takes the class of which an instance was requested as its first argument. The remaining arguments are those passed to the object constructor expression

So under the hood in `parent1 = Parent()`, Python's basically doing this:

```
_temp_new_parent = Parent.__new__(Parent)  # Inherited from "object.__new__"
Parent.__init__(_temp_new_parent)
parent1 = _temp_new_parent
```

(`_temp_new_parent` doesn't really exist, I'm just using it as an abstraction.)

Note that `__init__()` doesn't return anything, so in your code, `parent2 is None`. And if `__init__()` had set instance attributes, it would have set them on `parent1` since that's what you passed in.

Comment: Minor quibbles: It's invoking `Parent.__new__` (which just happens to be inherited from `object.__new__` in this case), and `__init__` doesn't return anything, so this code wouldn't actually work as is (rendering it accurately would be a three-liner; one to construct and assign to a temp, one to call `__init__` on the temp, one to bind the temp to `parent1`).

Comment: @Shadow Those are great points actually, and I wouldn't call them minor! I hadn't noticed until now that `parent2 is None` in OP's code. I'll fix my answer.